# Dill TypeError: cannot pickle 'sqlite3.Connection' object. No Sqlite anywhere in function

Tags: sqlite, pickle, multiprocess, dill

I am getting TypeError: cannot pickle 'sqlite3.Connection' object when attempting to pickle a function.  The thing is, I don't use sqlite anywhere in my project and definitely nowhere in this function.

Here is a minimal working example that shows the error:

```
    def test_outer(a):
        def test_inner(a):
            return a+1
        return a
    dill.dumps(test_outer)
```

Comment: Let's work out the issue here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/435.  Essentially, this exact code is run in the dill tests, and passes for all versions of python... so I expect it has to be something in your environment.

Comment: Did you run this in pyconsole from Pycharm ?